# Prove there exists a particular person at a party

Tags: proof-writing, pigeonhole-principle

There are $5^n$ people at a party. A girl (who is not part of the party) asks each person how many other people they are not friends with. When she sums everyone’s answers, she gets a number that is at most $5^k$, where $n ≤ k < 2n, n, k ∈ N.$ Assuming that each friendship is mutual (Person A is friends with person B, and vice versa) prove that there exists a person who has at least $5^n − 5^{k−n}$ friends.

I think we need to use the pigeonhole principle here, with $5^k$ as the number of holes, but I'm struggling to see what follows.

EDIT: people cannot be friends with themselves

Answer (score 1):

Suppose every person has $<5^n - 5^{k-n}$ friends. Then the girl only hears numbers that are $> 5^{k-n}$. What can you then say about the sum of those numbers?

Comment: the sum would have to be at least $5^{k-n}\cdot{5^n=5^k}$, which is then a contradiction?

Comment: Sorry I meant > $5^k$.

Comment: However, a person cannot be friends with themselves. So it would be "the girl only hears numbers that are $>5^{k-n}-1$". So, $(5^{k-n}-1)\cdot{5^n}$ would not give a contradiction.